# Setting up outline border according to main border

Tags: html, css

How to set the outline border according to the original border which is currently rectangle on hover? I would like to set this up according to its border..

```css
#hello {
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: 25%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hello:hover {
  outline: 2px solid #1abc9c;
}

#hello-left {
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: 25%;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hello-left:hover {
  outline: 2px solid #1abc9c;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello-left"></div>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `outline border according to main border` ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you edit the question please, to clarify exactly what you want and what you are currently getting (potentially via screenshots). Thanks.

Comment: clear it more please then only we will able to help

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you're all set...

```css
#hello {
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: 25%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#hello:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c);
}
#hello-left {
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: 25%;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#hello-left:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #1abc9c);
}
```

```html
<div id="hello-left"></div>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: Hello which is on box-shadow. But I would like to make it according to border.